# allow a filed can be inputted quotes php?

Tags: php, string

the main point is
allow a filed can be inputted quotes they ask me to use `pg_escape_string` this function.

`add1'skaka ==>add1''skaka`

i mean if we input `add1'skaka ==>add1''skaka` function will add 1 more quote.
 but into the `HTML` i don't want it display such 2 quotes.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pg_escape_string simply escapes your single quotes to allow strings to be safely stored into a PostgreSQL database. This needs to be done in order to avoid SQL injection attacks on your database. So yes it will double a quote in your database, but when you pull this data out of the database again, the extra quote will be gone.

```
add1'skaka ==>add1''skaka
```

In your database after a select you will only see add1'skaka

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for more information about SQL injection and the threats it poses

That or either: http://xkcd.com/327/ Little Bobby Tables =)

Answer (score 0):

> i mean if we input add1'skaka ==>add1''skaka function will add 1 more
>   quote. but into the HTML i don't want it display such 2 quotes.

You most likely have [`magic quotes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

[See how to disable them.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)